# JQuery Ajax sending over URL string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I seem to be having problems with sending over a string of a URL. The URL looks like this:

> http://www.thewebsitehere.com/mf2/stuff/dirhere.asp?sid=&nm=&type=Publishing&mod=Publions::Article&mid=8F3A7027421F87F791&SiteID=B824D34CAB8727A06DEA3467&tier=4&id=8964A4D50BB59A0AD48594A

Its sending all that information inside the JS but it only looks like this once it gets to the php page:

> http://www.thewebsitehere.com/mf2/stuff/dirhere.asp?sid=

My Ajax is set up like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: "type=add" + "&1A=" + pubName + "&1B=" + postID + "&1C=" + PostTitle + "&1D=" + timeStamp + "&1E=" + pdfLink + "&1F=" + imgLink + "&1G=" + fullArticleLink,
    url: "../wp-content/plugins/visual-editor-custom-buttons/js/wpDataSend.php",
    success: function(results) {
        if (results.indexOf("done") >= 0) {
            showNotifier(8000,'#43d32b','Title, Pub Name, Image, Date, PDF & Article link have been saved!');
        } else {
             showNotifier(8000,'#d32b2b','Could not save... Please try again!');
        }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
        console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        showNotifier(8000,'#d32b2b','Error: ' + textStatus + ' | ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

And I am gathering up the data from the PHP page like so:

```
$newtype     = $_POST['type'];
$pubName     = $_POST['1A'];
$postID     = $_POST['1B'];
$PostTitle     = $_POST['1C'];
$timeStamp     = $_POST['1D'];
$pdfLink     = $_POST['1E'];
$imgLink     = $_POST['1F'];
$Fullarticle   = $_POST['1G'];
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: You're posting to "wpDataSend.php" but getting "dirhere.asp"? What are the actual urls? Are you sending an `sid` param?

Comment: @Emmett It's just a link. Has nothing to do with the .php page that its sending the data to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). This will escape certain characters in the URL to conform with UTF-8 standards.

```
var encodedURL = encodeURIComponent(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can send post params [the right way](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) using

```
jQuery.ajax({
   ...
   data: {param1 : value1, param2: value2}
```

Comment: @DarkCthulhu: Will my PHP side be the same in order to gather that information? Will i need to change the **dataType** to **json**?

Comment: @StealthRT It would be the same. They are still going to arrive as post params.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data to this:

```
data: {type: "add", 1A: "pubName"....//and so on},
```

You have to put quotes and around the value.